# Painting fiberglass repair on kitchen sink

Tags: painting, sanding, primer

I recently did a fiberglass repair on my fiberglass kitchen sink. Now it's ready for paint. So I have a can of Rust-Oleum gloss white. Now it's been awhile but I'm pretty sure I should prime it first. Since we are moving we have some gallon cans of house paint and primers. But I know the Rust-Oleum needs to go over a sanded surface. So my question is what will send better,stick to the fiberglass, and be as glossy as the sink? I have latex  flat,satin,semi gloss, and maybe a can of acrylic, and one can of 100% acrylic latex. What is that?

Comment: Is the repair in an area of the sink that will get repeatedly wet? Consider appliance white epoxy paint.

Comment: Yes and it is. Multiple repairs in direct path of the water from faucet. Also in heavily abused area where pots pans and knives are most likely to knick or gouge the surface. I was able to minimize the evidence of abuse with some filling primer. Wet sanded it and top coated with Rust-Oleum. Looks good but now worried about future gouges and scratches. How long will it last? I thought there should be a more durable product out there.so I'm gonna research appliance epoxy paint right now. Thanks